# Laravel 9 auth using JSON data

Tags: json, laravel, authentication, laravel-9

I'm new to Laravel and use Laravel 9 for my REST API. The client sends data in JSON format when I want to authenticate the application. But I cannot authenticate JSON format with my below code. Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

```
public function loginUser(Request $request)
{
    $validateUser = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validateUser->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'Validation errror',
            'errors' => $validateUser->errors()
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you have defined your routes? api.php or web.php ?

Comment: Can you please check for the errors that what error you'll get in response. if you could paste the error that you get here that would very much will some how show us the point where this error occurs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your code needs some improvements.

Instead of doing manual validation, this way is better:

```
app/Exceptions/Handler.php

public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'Validation Error',
            'errors' => $e->errors()
        ], 422);
    }

    parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Now, in your controller, just:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required', (new \Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password(8))]
]);
```

And, to solve the JSON Problem, create a new middleware with: php artisan make:middleware ForceXmlHttpRequest

```
app/Http/Middleware/ForceXmlHttpRequest
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForceXmlHttpRequest
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

        return $next($request);
     }
}

app/Http/Middleware/Kernel.php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
...
'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\ForceXmlHttpRequest::class,
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

if u using postman you go to headers and wright

Key : Accept
Value : application/json